# Getting OpenMP running in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, openmp, codeblocks

I am trying to teach myself OpenMP using Windows 7, but I am having a hard time getting Code::Blocks to compile a basic hello world program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

I have made some progress, but there is one remaining persistent error that I can't get rid of.

I have -fopenmp in my compiler "Compiler->Compiler Settings->Other Options"

I have -gomp and -pthreads in "Compiler->Linker Settings->Other linker options"

I have C:\Program File (x86)\Codeblocks\MinGW\gcc\mingw32\bin in "Compiler->Toolchain exectuable->Additional Paths"

When I compile, I get the error: "ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread"

Can someone suggest what I might have set up wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The linker complains about a missing library.  pthreads is the library that implements the threading interface that your OpenMP implementation uses to do all the threading stuff.

The library is called "libpthread.a" (static version) and "libpthread.so" (dynamic version) on the disk.  Try to find these two on the file system under your MinGW directory.  They likely reside in a directory called "lib" or "lib64".   If either one is missing, then you might need to install an additional package.

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: It seems that pthreads is a unix library, not available for windows. I will see if I can find a wrapper for it, or something.

Comment: The pthread library should be part of your MinGW distribution.  Please have a look at the repository where you've installed MinGW from.